# How to get tel: to work in MarkDown or Asana?

Tags: markdown, asana

I want to put a clickable phone number into an Asana task, which means I could use MarkDown, but it keeps putting the http there.

`<a href="https://tel:123456798">`

Any ideas on how to force markdown to use the URL exactly as specified?

`<a href="tel:123456789">`